# Trazendo uma soma no SQLite Android

Tags: android, query, android-studio, sqlite

Estou com um problema no desenvolvimento de um App, seguinte, eu tenho uma lista que todos os dados de doações no banco, e nessa activity eu criei um TextView para receber o valor total daquelas doações, porém, tenho alguns problemas:
1° o campo valor no banco salvo em TEXT exp: 'R$ 120,00', 'R$ 325,65' e por isso faço uma soma com substr;
2° quando tento trazer o resultado daquela soma na verdade no app sai todo o texto da query, tentei de varias formas e esse é a atual situação do meu código:

```
    public String RetornarTotal(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor stmt = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(SUBSTR(VALOR,3,20)) FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    String total = stmt.getColumnName(0).toString();
    //String total = stmt.execute();
    return total;
}
```

Esse método é chamado no oncrete da activity e fica na classe SQLHelper, eu quero retornar somente o valor daquela soma, poderiam me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Use o método `getColumnIndex` para resgatar o o primeiro valor da sua query. Veja abaixo como deve ser feito:

```
Cursor stmt = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(SUBSTR(VALOR,3,20)) FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null); 

if (stmt.getCount() > 0) { 
    stmt.moveToFirst(); 
    do { 
           total = stmt.getString( stmt.getColumnIndex(0));
     } while (stmt.moveToNext()); 
         stmt.close(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Esse do-while é desnecessário, inclusive o if,  visto que essa query sempre irá retornar um único registro, mesmo se o banco estiver vazio (no caso resultará em soma igual a zero).

Answer (score 0):

Basta corrigir essa linha:

```
String total = stmt.getColumnName(0).toString();
```

Por:

```
String total = stmt.getString(0);
stmt.close();
```